# Code works but does not fill in the specified range

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Code is working but stops when to copy vlookup to all the cells (A1 to A5). Can someone help please? Thank you so much

```
  Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(RC2=""customer account"",INDEX('FEED DATA'!C[3],match('RAW DATA FILE'!R[1]C2,'FEED DATA'!C[5],0)),""""),"""")"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A5"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1:A5").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(RC2=""customer account"",INDEX('FEED DATA'!C4,match('RAW DATA FILE'!R[1]C2,'FEED DATA'!C6,0)),""""),"""")"
    Range("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using `Select` whenever possible.  You also need to qualify your ranges.  That means that you should include the Workbook and Worksheet otherwise you will be using whatever sheet is active, which may not be the one you want.  When doing so, you reduce the number of lines and make it more easily readable.  You can repeat for additional lines.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RAW DATA FILE")
    .Range("A1") = "=IFERROR(IF(RC2=""customer account"",INDEX('FEED DATA'!C[3],match('RAW DATA FILE'!R[1]C2,'FEED DATA'!C[5],0)),""""),"""")"
    .Range("A1").AutoFill .Range("A1:A5")
End With
```